# What is the relationship between ITRF and WGS84?

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84

Why are there people saying that "I am using WGS84(ITRF96)"?

There are newer version of ITRF. Will WGS84 follow it?

If so, what will be the influence to us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey I think this is your answer to the question:

http://www.quickclose.com.au/stanaway07pres.pdf

Dont know if it really helps but it does state what each is and that WGS is regularly aligned to ITRF.

Basically as you know, two types of Co-ordinate reference system.

Comment: or this is better as it is not purely Oz based.  http://www.gps.gov/multimedia/presentations/2009/09/ICG/wiley.pdf

Comment: Still, I doubt how different ITRF can be used at the same time.

Comment: you can set up a custom CRS using the official (+towgs84) parameters published by ITRF: http://itrf.ensg.ign.fr/ITRF_solutions/2008/tp_08-05.php. Dutch Marine Office has issued a Windows Porgram called PCtrans to do such calculations.

Comment: As far as i can see you should not be using several different versions at once only one for the project.  As Andre says, set a custom CRS which will allow something with a CRS of lets say WGS84 be transfromed so it displays correctly on OSGB64. I was just about to post the same link as he has done to show alterations.